# Return value from 2D array in Python class

Tags: python, arrays

I'll frame this in the fact that I'm kind of a newbie to Python and I'm taking my first stab at writing a class. What I'd like to achieve is for the class to open a text file and return a value from the file based on user input. The text file contains information in a 2D array like this:

```
 20,21,22
 23,24,25
 26,27,28
```

The value is retrieved from this text file and assigned to a new variable, so that the variable can be printed and also used later in a calculation. I've been able to do this without difficulty outside of a class, but getting this to work in a class has been frustrating. Here's the code I have so far in Python 2.7:

```
im_new = []

class Read(object):
    def __init__(self, row, col, newvar):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.newvar = newvar

        display_list = []
        self.newvar = []

        with open("Array.txt", "r") as data_file:
            for line in data_file:
                display_list.append(line.strip().split(','))

    def __str__(self):
        self.newvar = (display_list[self.row][self.col])
        return self.newvar

immem = Read( 1, 1, im_new)


print "OUTPUT: ", im_new
```

Ideally, I'd get "OUTPUT: 24", but instead I get "OUTPUT: []".  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're printing `im_new`, which is initialized as an empty `list` and never modified.

Comment: The first big problem is just that you forgot the `self.` before `display_list`. (You've got it on all of your other attributes, so I assume you understand what it means, and this is effectively just a typo?)

Comment: The second big problem is that you're printing `im_new` instead of `immem`. It's the latter that holds your `Read` instance, which has a `__str__` method, which does what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're mixing up two of your variables. `im_new` is an empty list; `immem` is a `Read` instance. Change the last line to `print 'OUTPUT:', immem`.

When you fix that, you'll get another problem: a `NameError` on `display_list`. This is because you forgot the `self.` on `display_list`, but in your `__init__` method and in your `__str__` method. (I assume you know what `self.` means, because you use it correctly for all of your other attributes.)

As a side note, it's a little weird to override `self.newvar` every time you get the `__str__` of your object. There's really no reason for this attribute to exist, at least in the code you've shown. So you could just do this:

```
class Read(object):
    def __init__(self, row, col):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col

        self.display_list = []

        with open("Array.txt", "r") as data_file:
            for line in data_file:
                self.display_list.append(line.strip().split(','))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.display_list[self.row][self.col]

immem = Read(1, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for walking me through this.  I'd been through a number of iterations of this, had gotten the errors you mention, which left me scratching my head.  Your explanation makes this clear.  Thank you.